# Python Modules and submodules in ROS catkin workspace

Tags: python, module, ros, rospy

I am trying to run python code in ROS and it includes a module (module not made for ROS) that I had to pip install. When I try running the code in my catkin workspace with roscore running, it cannot find the module I installed and gives me an ImportError. Any idea on how to run already created modules on ROS with rospy?

Comment: Have you tried to directly run like `python filename.py`? This might work. But, actually you have to include the library in your `CMakelists.txt` file.

Comment: @akshayk07 There is no need to mention Python modules in the CMakeLists.txt. As long as the Python package is installed properly, it should be usable without any additional configuration on the ROS package.

Comment: @Priyal Gosar: Can you use the Python module outside of the ROS package? E.g. can you import it in an interactive Python terminal?. As I wrote above, there should be no need for doing anything special in the ROS package.

Comment: put on your source code and error full trace back.

Answer (score 1):

### Making sure you can find the module

Here are 3 options.  They all should work and are in order of hackiness.

1. You can add the module to a package.xml like in this [ros numpy tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/numpy).

   ```
   <build_depend>python-numpy</build_depend>    
   <run_depend>python-numpy</run_depend>
   ```
2. Set your $PTYHONPATH environment variable in your .bashrc:

   ```
   export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/your/package_or_module
   ```
3. Inject a path to the module before importing it in your python code:

   ```
   import sys
   sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/your/package_or_module")
   ```

### Making sure you're running the program correctly

1. Resource your .bashrc and catkin workspace before running the program.
2. If you are trying to use `rosrun package_name filename.py` then you need to make sure the file is an executable:

   ```
   chmod +x pythonfile.py
   ```

   and the top of the python file should have the code:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   ```
3. Consider using python directly to run the file like akshayk07 mentioned

   ```
   python filename.py
   ```